# How to simulate a slow internet connection on an Android phone

Tags: wi-fi, internet, lan

I basically use internet using wifi which provides a very high speed internet and LAN connection. I would like to simulate a slow speed internet and LAN connection to understand how my web site works on slow speed. Is there any app that I can install on the android phone and simulate it?

Answer (score 7):

There is no such setting on Android phones, but you can use the Emulator for this. Install the Android SDK from [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) and launch it. On the DDMS view undet the `Emulator control` tab, you'll find the following options:

[image: Emulator control]

After you have created an emulator and ran it, you can set these values according to your preferences and test how different networks affect your site.

Answer (score 2):

When using Emulator is not an option for testing certain functionality (frequently), our team hot-spots for physical Android devices with an iOS device and uses the Network Link Conditioner on that. Obviously, for some this isn't an option, but it works very well and is easy to implement.